# I can't read data from json in excel

Tags: python, json, openpyxl

I'm trying to read data from a json file and translate it to excel, but I get an error. Thank you in advance.

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kryto\Desktop\csgo\xx.py", line 20, in 
sheet[row][0].value = hui['price']
File "C:\Users\kryto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 215, in value
self._bind_value(value)
File "C:\Users\kryto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 184, in _bind_value
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

Code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import json


    



book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active




with open('cs3.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:                       
    movie = json.load(file) 

row = 2
for hui in movie['3']:
    sheet[row][0].value = hui['price']
    



book.save("my_gulag.xlsx")
book.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the hui['price'] data type cannot be converted to an excel data type.
By example, the next line will produce the same error:

```
sheet[row][0].value = []
```

as openpyxl can not convert a list to an excel data type.

Review the data source or debug your code (ie. print hui['price'] before assigning to excel.)

This could be a comment but i do not have enough reputation to make comments and I think it will be useful to the person asking.

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe there is some other method to write data from the list?

Comment: @Coffeeinthebrain1, my answer shows code produce the same error, it will not solve your problem. To solve your problem you have to review the contents of every price on each element of movie['3']. You can add a line print(hui['price']) before the assignment line and see which data is provoking that error.